Subflow failing during decision element "The flow failed to access the value for because it hasn't been set or assigned"
I have a subflow that reviews dates, and if the dates are null I have the flow update them to the current date.
The flow is triggered by a Closed Won opportunity, then runs some updates on the Account record related to the opportunity. This flow worked before we added in the flow decision date checks.
I can debug the subflow successfully, but when I run it through the main record triggered flow, it bombs with the error message
The flow failed to access the value <date_value__c> for because it hasn't been set or assigned

I'm stumped. This is failing on a decision element that only checks if the date value on the account is null. I've tried using Is Blank too. This seems too simple to cause this many issues. What else can I check?



This error indicates that the field wasn't set or retrieved from the database. You'll need to use a GetRecords to get the correct fields for the account record, and then pass that value to the sub-flow.

Interesting. Even though I'm able to retrieve the field names I still need to use GetRecords?

@jdids Yes. A field retrieved from the database or set to null is a known unknown value. We know that the value is unknown. If neither of these have happened, we have an unknown unknown. We don't know if the value is unknown. You need to either use Get Records, or if it's because you're creating the account in the previous subflow, you must explicitly set the fields to a null value, so that you have known unknown values.
